# Cloud Spanner Unique index violation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I am using Cloud Spanner and am aware that one can interleave multiple tables eg: **Singers > Albums > Songs** (Albums is interleaved in Singers and Songs is interleaved in Albums).
These tables have the primary keys `singerId`, `albumId`, `songId` respectively. I will keep this example to phrase my question better.

I create a new song called `song1` which is from `album1` by `singer1`.

Then when I try to create another song called `song1` from `album1` with singerId `singer2`, I get the error:

```
 Query failed: Unique index violation on index IDX_Songs_songId_U_1A1B6C1202613A13 at 
 index key [song1,singer1,album1]. It conflicts with row [song1,singer1,album1] in table
 Songs.
```

Does the new Song entry need to have unique keys within the Songs and Albums tables even though the outermost `singerId` key is different?

In short, I want to know why `[singer1,album1,song1]` and `[singer2,album1,song1]` are seen as duplicates even though their parent key differs.

The minimal DDL is given below:

**Singers**

```
CREATE TABLE Singers (
  
  singerId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,

  firstName STRING(50) NOT NULL,

  surname STRING(50) NOT NULL,

  status INT64,

) PRIMARY KEY(singerId);
```

**Albums**

```
CREATE TABLE Albums (

  singerId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,

  albumId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,

  releaseDate DATE,

  genre BOOL,

) PRIMARY KEY(singerId, albumId),

  INTERLEAVE IN PARENT Singers ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

**Songs**

```
CREATE TABLE Songs (

  singerId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,

  albumId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,

  songId STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,

  duet BOOL,

) PRIMARY KEY(singerId, albumId, songId),

  INTERLEAVE IN PARENT Albums ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the new Song entry need to have unique keys within the Songs and Albums tables even though the outermost singerId key is different?

Short answer is no.

What happened in your case is that there exists a unique index (`IDX_Songs_songId_U_1A1B6C1202613A13`) that enforces the uniqueness of "songId" itself.

It would be good to paste the schema here so we can further discuss the use case.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I edited the question to include the DDL. Hope this is sufficient?

Comment: Can you grab the whole schema for the database (by clicking the `SHOW EQUIVALENT DDL` button in the overview page)? There should be a unique index somewhere.

Comment: Okay, I got the schema by clicking `SHOW EQUIVALENT DDL`, but I still can not see any indexes created (especially not unique indexes). I searched the schema (ctrl+f) for index and found nothing. However, I did think it could be a foreign key relationship. Do you think this could be a cause? For example, in my schema I have a table `SongReports` that has a foreign key referencing the `songId` in songs.

Comment: Yes. Given the random number in the unique index name, I also think it is somehow generated (instead of you creating it). How is the foreign key defined? Is it on the `songId` itself, or on the combination of `singerId, albumId, songId`? If the former case, it should explain the error (you cannot reference two different rows).

Comment: The FK is defined on `songId`. That should explain the error. I'm gonna change some things and give it a go. Quick Q: It does make sense to define the FK as `singerId, albumId, songId`, but is it possible to define a FK like that?

Comment: Yes, you can put multiple columns in the foreign key constraints.

Comment: You're a legend. Thanks for your help - the problem is resolved.